# how to reduce the size of all component in sencha application

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sass

i am developing sencha android mobile app, every component in sencha is looking very big and font size also big and i finished my application,but finally i have to do styling.

**i have to reduce the every component size using css, how can i start, i am not very good at css and also i hared about sass.**

what are the things i need to look at and I used below css so for.

```
    .btnfacebook {
    background: url(../images/facebook.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

.btnmyapp {
    background: url(../images/myapp.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
.btntwitter {
    background: url(../images/twitter.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
.my-dataview-item {
    background: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.my-dataview-item img {
    width: 50px;
    height : 43px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.my-dataview-item #count {
    float: right;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 999px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    width: -4px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    font: 14px Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.my-dataview-item #time {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.x-list-item-label div{
    padding-left: 3px;  
}
#profilePhoto {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
#profilePicture{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best that you use sass, and generate the css file like that. You can set a default font size (by only using 1 line) and the rest of the sizes are calculated upon that size.

A good tutorial on how to start can be found here:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/theming